# How to populate ListBox from Dictionary Values?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, dictionary, listbox

Net

I am attempting to create a function that will allow a user to input  text into a RTB and if that text exists in a Dictionary as a Key then a `listbox` is populated by all the `values` of the `dictionary` whose `key` they are related to , each `value` populates the `listbox` in a new line.

the 1st line is highlighted and the user can press the `enter button` and replace the text in the RTB with the highlighted text .

I'm new to VB so I do not know much .

this is what I have so far.

```
Public Class Oxnay

Private Sub Oxnay_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Tsort()
End Sub
Private TDictionary As Dictionary(Of String, String())

Public Sub Tsort()
    TDictionary = New Dictionary(Of String, String())

    TDictionary.Add("ape", {"pl", "tz", "xu"})
    TDictionary.Add("lor", {"tv", "px"})
End Sub

Private Sub RichtextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim lastword As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Split(" ").Last

    If RichTextBox1.ContainsKey(lastword) Then
        'display each string of the dictionary array related to lastword in different lines
        'highlight first line
        'Some[Code]
    Else
        ListBox1.Text = ""
    End If
End Sub
```

End Class

Comment: FYI, that's not VBScript, it's VB.Net...

Comment: my mistake . I will fix that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first "lookup" part, try something like:

```
Private Sub RichtextBox1_TextChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles RichTextBox1.TextChanged
    Dim lastword As String = RichTextBox1.Text.Trim.Split(" ").Last
    ListBox1.Items.Clear()
    If Not IsNothing(TDictionary) AndAlso TDictionary.ContainsKey(lastword) Then
        ListBox1.Items.AddRange(TDictionary(lastword))
    End If
End Sub
```

Then to replace the currently selected text with the selection from the ListBox:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    If ListBox1.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then
        If RichTextBox1.SelectedText <> "" Then
            RichTextBox1.SelectedText = ListBox1.SelectedItem.ToString
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: wow , that's amazing . I would have never thought of coding the function that way . all that I need to do now is manipulate the text replacement function . I seem to be having a problem with it at the moment

Comment: "... I am attempting to create a function that will allow a user to input text into a RTB"  So how does that work with the RichTextBox as ReadOnly?....

Comment: I use RichTextBox1.text = RichTextBox1.Text + "a"  If the A button is pressed .

I got it to work . thanks again =]